# Google Drive not showing up in Nautilus even with accounts synced

Tags: nautilus, google-drive

I have logged into my Google Account using the `online accounts` from settings on Ubuntu 17.04 running GNOME.

However, even though I have selected "on" for files, I do not see my google drive in Nautilus (see image).

[image]

Is there any way I can force it to appear?

Thanks